# EF code first and two way relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Parent)
    .WithMany(t => t.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
```

Here I defined a basic 1-to-many relationship. What if I do not want to have Children property exposed at all in Model, but still want to have synchronization of values between Parent and ParentId. How would I go defining such "relationship"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will call `WithMany` without any parameter:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Parent)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
```